# Did millions sign up for association health plans after President Trump's executive order?

Tags: united-states, politics, healthcare

President Trump just said [this](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/12/28/us/politics/trump-interview-excerpts.html) in an interview with the New York Times:

> Now here’s the good news. We’ve created associations, millions of people are joining associations. Millions. That were formerly in Obamacare or didn’t have insurance. Or didn’t have health care. Millions of people.

This is a reference to an executive order President Trump issued earlier this year expanding the use of association health plans.

My question is, is it true that millions of people joined association health plans after President Trump's executive order?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No. This is indeed a reference to an executive order, but the regulations related to it aren't in effect yet.

> Trump is referring to an executive order, mentioned above, but it has no force in law on its own and no one has yet joined these associations. The rules spelling out how the executive order would work have not been issued yet, so Trump is simply making up his “millions” number. <sub>source: [Washington Post: In a 30-minute interview, President Trump made 24 false or misleading claims](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/fact-checker/wp/2017/12/29/in-a-30-minute-interview-president-trump-made-24-false-or-misleading-claims/?utm_term=.e01687094dd8)</sub>

[NPR](https://www.npr.org/2017/12/29/574504669/fact-check-trumps-new-york-times-interview-on-russia-taxes-health-care-and-more) goes into this in a bit more depth.

Comment: As an aside: Critics on the [left](https://www.vox.com/policy-and-politics/2017/12/29/16829806/trump-interview-new-york-times) and [right](http://www.nationalreview.com/corner/455008/trump-health-care-yuval-levin) have called Trumps answer "incoherent" and "word salad" - so there is room for interpretation on what exactly he is talking about - but all sources I have found agree that him referring to the executive order is the only thing that makes sense, and that the executive order is not yet put into practice.

Comment: So, not only is the statement that "millions joined" false, even the statement "we've created associations" is incorrect, rather they are still in the process of creating them?